# Play! Framework: Apache mod_proxy occasionally delivers Proxy Error

Tags: proxy, apache-http-server, http-proxy, reverse-proxy

The backend is a Play! Framework application.

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /entries/topic~showcase

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Apache/2.2.22
```

Here is the site configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName www.xxx.com
  ServerAlias xxx.com
  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass /investor http://127.0.0.1:81/investor
  ProxyPass /phppgadmin http://127.0.0.1:81//phppgadmin
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/ keepalive=On
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

After adding *keepalive=On*, I could notice an improvement. But the Proxy Error still occurs!